# Счетчик, не обнуляемый при перезагрузке страницы

Tags: jquery, javascript

[Создание отсчета времени на jQuery](http://www.rudebox.org.ua/creating-loading-indicator-rudebox/) - здесь то, что мне надо (нужно сделать так, чтоб при обновлении страницы индикатор не обнулялся). Там нужно что-то с js файлом сделать, а что не очень понятно, нужен хотя бы намек.
хмм а посмотрите реализацию тогда такого [счетчика](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub_id=32&id=1135)

**`Цель: Сделать отсчет времени от заданного числа!`**

Answer (score 1):

У меня такое предположение что сделать такое не получится.

Вы слишком много хотите от `jQuery`.

Comment: вы не правы!

Comment: Может быть. Но скажу одно: нормально сделать такое не получится.

Answer (score 1):

даю намек: кукисы, но там прийдется попотеть!

Comment: кукисы и сессии в крайне не правильный подход, а если пользователь закрыл браузер а потом открыл, кукисы или сессия уничтожатся, поэтому нужно что то другое. Ну это как время на js обновляешь, а оно заного  не начинается!

Comment: @MaximPro, тогда AJAX + БД.
P.S.: не назвал бы кукисы "крайне неправильным подходом".
И не говорите только, что БД тоже не подходит.

Comment: можно но не желательно(лучше задействовать время на js а впрочем вот ссылка там таймер обратного отсчета без ajax и бд http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub_id=32&id=1135)

Comment: бд подходит но не хочется базу нагружать запросами

Comment: Я не уверен, что это подойдёт для вашего случая.

Answer (score 1):

rtfm [WebStorage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/):

```
var counter=localStorage.getItem("counter") || 0;
//document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = counter;
setInterval(function(){
  counter++;
  localStorage.setItem("counter",counter);
  //document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = counter;
},1000);
...  
<span id="counter"></span>
...
```

Comment: Будет работать в новых браузерах. И только.

Comment: IE Firefox Safari Chrome Opera iPhone Android
8.0+ 3.5+ 4.0+ 4.0+ 10.5+ 2.0+ 2.0+

вполне достаточно, имхо.
проф http://htmlbook.ru/html5/storage

Answer (score 0):

У меня немного извращенный вариант. Может быть использовать **GET** параметр для количества процентов?

Comment: GET? Точно? Может быть `hash`?

Comment: не ну что вы вообще выкиньте ajax и бд(php and mysql) только джава или джуквери